# Use WiFi router connected to Ethernet not directly to Modem

Tags: router, wireless-networking

My WiFi signal is really bad in some areas of my house.

I have a spare router and was wondering if it's possible to use it connected with Ethernet, and not directly connected to the modem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, just be sure not to configure it as a DHCP server...

Comment: and that you use channels which don't interfere with each other, eg 1 and 11.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1. Use the router as accesspoint - this way is the best, if your router had the option. this minimizes the processing load on the router.

Option 2. Use the router as "router" - just set it into a different subnet and use the upstream router just as you use the modem. The WAN set as DHCP and remember to set the DHCP server on the router onto a different subnet.

No matter what you do:

First optimize the wireless network - check which channel is least used, and then use the channel. Remember 802.11 channels do overlap. and set different routers into different channel unless you are doing wireless bridging.

And then consider using gain antennae instead of getting another router into the network.

Comment: Could you elaborate on just what you are trying to accomplish with Option 2 and how your configuration would look to accomplish it? As I understand, the original intent of subnets was to aid in routing. A home LAN should not need more than basic "here or there" routing so I do not understand how different subnets would be useful in the context of a home LAN.

Comment: actually option 2 is not useful when option 1 can be used. some routers, particularly noname brand from china, sometimes could only be configured this way when required as an "accesspoint".

Comment: @irrational John, option 2 is just fine, and often easier than 1 (though I also prefer 1).  Whatever the 'original intent of subnets' might have been, this is certainly a tried and true pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article over at smallnetbuilder.com goes over the steps to do what I think you said you want to do. Hope it helps.

[How To Add an Access Point to a Wireless Router](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/30355-how-to-add-an-access-point-to-a-wireless-router)

Answer (score 0):

- Disable DHCP
- Disable any extra stuff

This works, but ideally you would set the device as an accesspoint rather than a gateway.  This avoids an extra hop, simplifies subnetting, and can avoid a double NAT depending on configuration.  This setting is device dependent, but most products have this option.